# AJAX communication on visualforce > Internet Explorer 8/9 issues

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a Salesforce app and the developers are struggling to get it to work with IE8/9.

It works fine on chrome, firefox and safari but there appears to be an issue related to the APEX communication between ie8/9 and Visualforce.

The 'fixes' in the following blog post have been tried and they dont seem to fix the issue.
http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/03/visualforce-rerender-and-internet-explorer-9.html

The problem appears to be with the AJAX communication between Visualforce and Apex code, in that communication information/signals from the presentation layer (Visualforce), is not reaching the business layer (Apex code) in IE8/9.

Does anyone know if there is a viable fix or workaround for the the problems associated with AJAX communication between Visualforce and Ajax layers on Internet Explorer 8 and 9?

Comment: Are you using apex tags? or just writing plane html/javascript in your visualforce page? Perhaps show us snippets of the controller/extension and visualforce page which aren't working

Comment: Can you check whether you are getting any JS error?
Please post some code snippet of yours which would be helpful for everybody to suggest a workaround.

Comment: It'd be useful if you posted a code snippet that you think is not working in IE 8/9. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, please post some code so that we can see what might be the issue. It could be any number of things. Likely it is an issue with your DOM but we'd only be guessing without seeing the VF source at least.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. I will try and get some further information from the developer tomorrow and post.

Comment: Dear all, here is a link to the fix suggested by salesforce T3 support. hope it helps others in a similar situation............. http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000RduwAAC

Comment: @Garry2013, If the link you've mentioned above has helped, you may update it as answer. Thus your post will be of real help to others.

Answer (score 5):

Gary2013 has the answer in a comment but has not been back to post it as an answer. To help others, the link to the bug report and work around is http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000RduwAAC